# What would be the effect of wind in the wavefronts coming from a isotropic source?

Tags: optics, waves, acoustics

Consider a situation where a isotropic point source is kept on ground and its emanating sound waves which would be radial outwards . Consider now wind starts  blowing towards left side , what would be the waveforms pattern now ? Will it be like superposition of two velocities (i.e. velocity of sound and velocity of wind) if not what is the case ? The official answer given was this type which i dont actually understand [horizontal wind is blowing towards left with a constant and uniform velocity ] : [image]

Answer (score 0):

If the wind has a constant velocity, the effect is just to change the reference frame.  If you imagine moving at the same speed as the wind, the atmosphere will look like it is stationary and the ground and the source are moving instead.  If we idealize the ground as being perfectly flat and smooth and we ignore viscous boundary layers, we can pretend the point source is in free space and at the end just take the top part of the pattern.

Are you familiar with the "waveform pattern" of a moving point source in a static medium?  The pattern in the case you have described is identical.  If you are not, then you might think of the situation like this: sound is radiated from the source, creating a circular wavefront (the contours of the rays).  As time progresses, the circle radius increases at the normal sound speed.  However, because the wind is blowing, the circle center moves in the direction of the wind at the speed of the wind.  Thus, successive wavefronts are displaced from each other.  I don't know how much explanation you need, so I will leave it there for now.

See my little drawing for an example.  I apologize for the wiggly lines.

[image: Wavefronts and rays for a point source in wind.]

Comment: Sir given was horiozontal wind blowing towards left with constant uniform velocity

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually draw the picture out and was going on my intuition for that last comment.  I drew it out, and the official answer is correct.  I am including my little drawing for clarification.