# Wind and sound waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, reference-frames, acoustics, relative-motion

[image]

The official answer is C.

Why not A? If I add a horizontal component of velocity towards left, why would the path become curved?

Comment: Note: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692246/ does not fully answer my question

Comment: I think I understand that my problem is that I am treating a travelling longitudinal wave somewhat like a single travelling particle. However, I still can’t solve this.