# Can wind change the direction of sound propagation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

**CONTEXT:**

I asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/715627/wind-and-sound-waves) and the [first answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/715716/339095) stated that wind cannot change the flux of sound waves through an area.

Why is this? I understand that sound waves are basically a bunch of medium particles performing SHM. Now if I add to their velocity, a component perpendicular to the direction of SHM (i.e. from the wind; I’m not considering the component parallel to it), won’t it affect the direction of sound waves?

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I add to their velocity, a component perpendicular to the direction of SHM

The velocity is not added to the sound rays of the sound waves, it is added to the *[fluid that is ai](https://howthingsfly.si.edu/ask-an-explainer/how-can-air-be-fluid-if-its-gas-arent-fluids-liquid)r* .

> won’t it affect the direction of sound waves?

Yes, it will change the direction according to the fluid motion of the gas/air.

[image: linked]

c in the [linked question b](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/715627/wind-and-sound-waves)ecause a turbulence is forced on the air  by the horizontal wind, and the lines reflect the turbulence as the particles of air,which willcarry the sound, flow.

Comment: Okay, but could you please explain why not A or D?

Comment: How could straight lines remain in a turbulent flow, for a; d is opposite to the turbulance created from  right to left, pushes the air and makes it turn

Comment: I mean, @annav if you push the straight vertical line towards left, won’t it become like the center line of d and not c?

Comment: I have been saying that the lines are imaginary rays of sound **imaginary** , you cannot push them,  only air can be pushed. the lines have to move with the flow

Comment: Ok thanks  :)